# How to pass template variable to slice filter in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to slice loop in django template with variable

**USUAL WAY**

```
{% for article in module.module_article_key.module_article_category.article_category_key.all|slice:":2" %}
    {{ article.article_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

**WHAT NEEDS**

```
{% for article in module.module_article_key.module_article_category.article_category_key.all|slice:":module.module_article_key.module_article_count" %}
    {{ article.article_title }}
{% endfor %}
```

so we have working variable **{{ module.module_article_key.module_article_count }}**

normaly this variable gives integer value stored for this module, however wen i use it to slice loop - nothing happens

Comment: Hang on, `module_article_category` appears to be a relation, since you access `article_category_key.all` on it. So how can it give an integer? You should probably show your models.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed variable, it was corrent in project, I made mistake asking question (edited now)

Comment: what is your Django version?

Comment: I use django 1.11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to cast `module_article_count` to string first then making `articleSlice` via nested [{% with %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with) and use the resulting template variable in `slice` filter as follow:

```
{% with  articleCount=module.module_article_key.module_article_count|stringformat:"s" %}
    {% with  articleSlice=":"|add:articleCount %}
        {% for article in module.module_article_key.module_article_category.article_category_key.all|slice:articleSlice %}
            {{ article.article_title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to accept+upvote if it helped :)